# Are there seven consecutive annual dates which result in Monday-Sunday?

Tags: logical-deduction, time

Choose a date that's a Monday, e.g. 1st Jan 2024. Then keep adding 1 year until you have seven dates in a row that are the days of the week in order (Monday to Sunday).

Does such a date combination exist?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes

> The day of the week will either increase by 1 or 2 when adding a full year, since `365 mod 7 = 1` and for leap years, `366 mod 7 = 2`

So

> We need 7 consecutive years which do not contain a leap year. A rule for leap years is that if the year is divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400, the leap year is 'skipped'. E.g. The year 2000 was a leap year, but the years 1700, 1800, and 1900 were not.

Example sequence:

> Monday, April 1st 2097
>  Tuesday, April 1st 2098
>  Wednesday, April 1st 2099
>  Thursday, April 1st 2100
>  Friday, April 1st 2101
>  Saturday, April 1st 2102
>  Sunday, April 1st 2103

Comment: Trivia: Conventionally, 1700 is a leap year. This is because the majority of the world only switched to Gregorian calendar from Julian after that.

Comment: "Give us back our 11 days!" In Britain (and her dominions), the calendars were aligned to cancel out the accumulated discrepancy. There were **no** days between 2nd and 14th September 1752.